# How might I find an element in goquery like I would with find_all in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: go, web-scraping, goquery

I want to accomplish with [goquery](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) the same what is done
by the following Python code (the xpath in the comment specifies what is my target):

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
def getSnatch49women():
    r = get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_weightlifting")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"mw-content-text"}).find_all("div")[0]
    record = div.find_all("tbody")[1].find_all("tr")[2].find_all("td")[1].get_text()
    return record

print(getSnatch49women())#Prints "94 kg"
```

I've been trying to utilize goquery's `Eq()` instead of BeautifulSoup's
`find_all()[]` but I'm not getting the result I need. My Golang code:

```
package main

import ( "fmt"
"log"
"net/http"
"github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery" 
)

func getSnatch49() string {
  var record string
  res, e := 
  http.Get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_weightlifting")
  if e != nil { fmt.Println(e.Error()) } 
  defer res.Body.Close()
  if res.StatusCode != 200 {
    log.Fatalf("failed to fetch data: %d %s", res.StatusCode, res.Status)
  }

  doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(res.Body)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  doc.Find("#mw-content-text div").Eq(0).Eq(8).Find("tbody").Eq(2).Eq(1).Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
  record = s.Text()

  })
  return record
}

func main() {

  fmt.Println(getSnatch49())
}
```